# Footer at the bottom using position:fixed but maintaining space-between

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to set my footer at the bottom of the page and I managed to do so with the CSS properties "position:fixed" and "bottom:0".
However, by doing so, my two DIV of the footer have not anymore a space between them.
I am stuck in solving this issue.

My html:

```
<div class="footer">
  <div class="footer-links">
    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-copyright">
     <%= link_to "Creato da: F & F", poetries_path =%>

  </div>
</div>
```

My css:

```
.footer {
  background: #F4F4F4;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0px 50px;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
}
.footer-links {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.footer-links a {
  color: black;
  opacity: 0.15;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
.footer-links a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.footer .fa-heart {
  color: #D23333;
}
```

Basically I want the DIV `footer-links` at the bottom-left of the page and the DIV `footer-copyright` at the bottom-right. However, now they are at the bottom left both even if I used `space-between`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a wrapper element (i.e. `DIV`) into your `.footer-copyright` DIV, containing/wrapping the two elements the footer should contain, and apply the CSS to it which you previously had for `.footer-copyright`, i.e.:

```
.wrapper_inside_footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%
}
```

(`height: 100%` is to make it expand to the full height of the footer to get the vertical centering right)

Answer (score 0):

what I'm saying is that I did exactly what I did?

```css
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .footer {
    background: #f4f4f4;
    height: 100px;
    padding:0 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .footer-links {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .footer-links a {
    color: black;
    opacity: 0.15;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
  }
  .footer-links a:hover {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .footer .fa-heart {
    color: #d23333;
  }
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="footer-links">
    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i> I</a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i> F</a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i> T</a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i> L</a>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-copyright">
     <%= link_to "Creato da: F & F", poetries_path =%>

  </div>
</div>
```